# Loopback - Hide Request Access Token

Tags: node.js, access-token, loopbackjs, node-modules, loopback

I have security issue when I use Loopback API. The issue is that Access Token is accessible via query URL / Header. Can I hide the Access Token when I call Loopback API or Is There any setting that I can put Access Token in Body with POST function?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always be using HTTPS if you are doing authorization in your API.

Just hiding the data from the URL won't help you prevent attacks since the info will still be sent in plaintext inside the headers/cookies.

If you enable HTTPS and redirect HTTP queries to HTTPS then only the server and the client can see the value, which is the expected behavior.

This will also prevent the login data to be sent in plaintext as well, which is always a bad idea.

[You can check this document on deployment](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Preparing-for-deployment.html) or try [this example project for enabling SSL](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-ssl).

Comment: Hiding *access_token*s from the URLs is actually a good idea even using HTTPs. There are many ways to exploit this, like accidentally bookmarking the URL, browsing the history, or even trying to share link.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of sending the Access Token as GET parameter, try to send it as `Authorization` Header.

Header: `Authorization: $ACCESS_TOKEN`

More infos [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html)

Comment: Hi Tobias,

Thank you for your feedback, I try it, but, it still expose Access Token in Header. Example :

GET /api/AgentParties HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.53.6.13:3000
Authorization: LQT09Vobp5ZYzutBdETooEU28ydOvG6QyEaycAhGGE6WZsLCQZZ8g2eCrEKw7J3t
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3ec25658-7e8c-fcf5-26ef-1f69a2e3473c

Thank You.

Comment: @Xnuxer why/which logging tool do you use?

Comment: Burp Suite, but it has been solved when I convert to https (SSL), insted of using http. Thank You Tobias.

Comment: @Xnuxer Did it automatically hide the access token? I read this and switched to https and the token is still exposed.

Comment: Hi @DavidLuong, you can't hide access token. for security reason you must use HTTPS with certificate pinning if you use mobile apps.

Comment: @Xnuxer thanks for the reply. I read up about this and now I am making the call in the backend instead of the front end to hide access tokens. Let me know about this approach.